# Type class constraint with multiple variables

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a hard time to grasp the following type class constraint of a Monad Reader function, that receive multiple variables,

```
local :: MonadReader r m => (r -> r) -> m a -> m a
```

How to correctly understand the type class constraint? which one is the type constructor, `r` or `m` or both? (from the `m a` part it suggests the type constructor is `m`).

Compared with for example the bind function, where the type class constraint admitted only single parameter;

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Unlike the local function above, it's obvious and easy to comprehend that the type class constraint for the bind function demand type constructor `m` to be a Monad instance.

Comment: http://adit.io/posts/2013-06-10-three-useful-monads.html#the-reader-monad has a nice pictorial explanation of the reader monad.

Answer (score 2):

In those cases it's best to look at the class ([MonadReader](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#t:MonadReader)) here.

There you'll find this:

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
```

and quite a bit more.

So here `m` is some monad and `r` will be the thing you read from (`MonadReader` is a so called monad-transformer ... well ok not quite - it's the class that is common to all those transformers - `ReaderT` is the transformer ... but that's really horrible to explain ... sorry)

`local` is used to *change* the thing you read from (I like to think of it as the configuration or the environment) - the `r->r` part - giving you a computation in the monad `m` that will do this change.

And if you read on in the documentation there is even an example of how to use this:

```
calculateContentLen :: Reader String Int
calculateContentLen = do
    content <- ask
    return (length content);

-- Calls calculateContentLen after adding a prefix to the Reader content.
calculateModifiedContentLen :: Reader String Int
calculateModifiedContentLen = local ("Prefix " ++) calculateContentLen

main = do
    let s = "12345";
    let modifiedLen = runReader calculateModifiedContentLen s
    let len = runReader calculateContentLen s
    putStrLn $ "Modified 's' length: " ++ (show modifiedLen)
    putStrLn $ "Original 's' length: " ++ (show len)
```

as you can see `local` is used here to add `"Prefix "` in front of the string

**please note** that the monad `m` in this example is **not** `IO` - it's `Identity` (basically nothing - it has no effect)

---

(I hope it's ok to copy and paste it ... if not please let me know or remove it)

Comment: It's under a BSD-style license, so it should be safe to copy and paste with attribution.

Comment: Firstly thanks @Carsten for your answer. My difficulty to understand the type of the local function, streamed out from the type class constraint.

For the bind function, I could easy see that the `m` is required to be a Monad instance while for the local function, at first I thought the product of `r m` is required to be a Monad instance. This would be confusing since obviously the kind of `r` is `*` and the kind of `m` is `* -> *`. Does this means that the declaration of type class constraint can't be taken as a functional operation?